# How to add 'shine' overlay to a div?

Tags: html, css, overlay, gradient

How can I add a nice overlay like the one in the following image?

[image]

Consider the following HTML, how would I add an overlay like that? I know I can use a gradient on top of it, and apply it diagonally, but can I curve it as well?

```
<div class="photostrip">
  <div class="overlay" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a21tM.jpg" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a21tM.jpg" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a21tM.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

[Here's something I've tried](http://codepen.io/sergiotapia/pen/eJwGm) (I've oversaturated the overlay so it's easily seen), but it's not quite the shape I'm looking for.

```
body { background-color: #4b74db; }

.photostrip {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 185px;
  background-color: #000;  
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 3px #333;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;

  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 403px;
    /* This adds the nice overlay. */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.60) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 100%);
  }


  img {
    display: block;    
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a transparent png overlay be the easiest solution, assuming the size doesn't change?

Comment: @ArthurMigdal: Trying to mitigate the usage of images, if it's possible with CSS it's better.

Comment: @ArthurMigdal: I see, let me take a look - didn't think of that approach.

Comment: Please don't post links to off-site code without including the code in your question.

Comment: @Serg: You could add `background-color: #fff; opacity: .3;` (or a gradient) to `.overlay`, **or** change `border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 403px;` to `border-top-left-radius: 200px 403px;` and add `background-color: #000; opacity: .3;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work for you: http://codepen.io/defo550/pen/Fcsxo

```
.photostrip {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 185px;
  background-color: #fff;  
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 3px #333;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;

  /* Remove default list stylings*/
  list-style: none;

  /* provide a position context for our   pseudo element */
  li {
    position: relative;
  }

  img {
    display: block;  
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
  }
}

/* overlay styles
  create pseudo element  
*/
.photostrip li:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
       /* position above img */
        z-index: 5;

        width: 175px;
        height: 120px;
        top: 0;
        left: 5px;

/* overlay styles */
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.33) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.33) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 61%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
      }

<ul class="photostrip">
 <li><img /></li>
 <li><img /></li>
 <li><img /></li>
</ul>
```

I put your images in an unordered list and then created a pseudo-element on the li (that wraps each image) that has a background gradient with the desired effect ( or close ) of your image above.

You could also target each li separately in the CSS to change up the background gradient.

Comment: Not quite, it's not curved like in the example picture.

Comment: You can replace the linear-gradient and use a radial-gradient, instead of a pseudo-element on each li, just create one on the ul.  You can also explore an SVG option as well.

Comment: The amount of dead image links in this thread, is way too high!

Answer (score 0):

i think this close to what you are looking for you just have to play with the numbers 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GDvju

i just added another layer and gave it a top left radius

```
body { background-color: #4b74db; }

.photostrip {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 185px;
  background-color: #000;  
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 3px #333;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;

  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    /* This adds the nice overlay. */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.60) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 100%);
  }
  .overlay2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 300px 600px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.60) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 100%);
  }


  img {
    display: block;    
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty slick solution keshav!